# Is there any rsync option to avoid errors on sockets in the source

Tags: rsync, unix-sockets

I'm trying to back up a user's files on a remote machine, but I can't find any rsync option to avoid errors ...

```
++ rsync -a --no-D --delete --stats '--exclude=.cache/*' --password-file=a_secret backup@fredhome::fred /mnt/rusers/fred/
rsync: readlink_stat("/.adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Synchronizer/Commands" (in fred)) failed: Permission denied (13)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
rsync: readlink_stat("/.config/opera/oauc_pipe_r" (in fred)) failed: Permission denied (13)    
rsync: readlink_stat("/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent" (in fred)) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: readlink_stat("/.google/desktop/a1_sock" (in fred)) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

(This is one error from each folder, there are several others). The problem sources are sockets. I'd like to tell it to skip sockets, but I've tried `-rlptgo` in place of `-a`, `--no-D`, `--no-specials` , all without any success. I don't want to force `--delete` on any old error. I don't know if it's wise to completely exclude the folders containing the sockets, and excluding the sockets one by one could be a long game of whack-a-mole.

Have I missed something in the rsync doc?

Comment: Note that the errors are all "Permission denied" errors, not errors relating specifically to sockets or named pipes.

Comment: Yes, but it's running as root!

Comment: Correction. It's running as root at the receiving end. The rsyncd daemon at the other end is running as chroot with uid=fred and gid=fred. The sockets that cause the errors are all uid=fred and gid=fred. So why permission errors? Switching to root might be interesting, but isn't a good idea for the long term.